# How to delete from table permenantly (without log) and using where condition

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have table that keep procedures of many processes and sometimes I need to delete processes with specific date inside the table that 100% I won't need them again,
but the problem is that it's a lot of data which makes the log file bigger and bigger.
I don't want a way of shrinking the log file for some reasons.
and the truncate as well which delete all the rows.
any help to delete these specific data permanently with where condition without the log file backup.

Comment: What edition of SQL Server? Standard? Enterprise?

Comment: sqlserver 2008 r2 express and standard @MartinSmith

Comment: So you can't use table partitioning then...

Answer (score 0):

use SET ROWCOUNT 10000 (or whatever chunk makes sense to keep logging under control)
then run your delete statement in a loop until no records are deleted, do log backups if needed between each iteration.